# How to get back as x when entered as x(bar)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a simple program that works as a NOT gate. I have come to the end but I have no idea how to get the trench removed when (bar) is inserted. This way, I also have an idea to create gates like AND, OR. What I need to learn is to do this and point out the flaws.

Answer (score 1):

```
def NOTgate(a):
    return not a
print(NOTgate(1))

notgate truth table  
   input |  output
      1         0
      0         1
```

so return the not input